# MongoDB Aggregation Project check if array contains

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following document:

```
{
    _id : 21353456,
    username : "xy",
    text : "asdf",
    comments : [
        {
            username : "User1",
            text : "hi",
        },
        {
            username : "User2",
            text : "hi1",
        },
        {
            username : "User3",
            text : "hi2",
        },
        {
            username : "User4",
            text : "hi3",
        }

    ]
}
```

Now I want to get the username, text and comments with aggregation and project. In addition I also want a boolean if the comments array contains an username with "User1". I have this, but it doesn't work.

```
db.posttest.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
          {
            username: 1,
            text: 1,
            comments : 1,
            hasComment: { $eq: [ "comments.$.username", "User1" ] },
            _id: 0
          }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to first `unwind` the comments, and then use a `group` with a little trick. If you want to omit the `_id`, then you would also need to do a simple project. Here is the full aggregation pipeline:

```
db.posttest.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$comments" },
  { $group : {
    _id : "$_id",
    username : { $first : "$username" },
    text : { $first : "$text" },
    comments : { $push : "$comments" },
    hasComments : { $max : { $eq : [ "$comments.username", "User1" ] } }
  }},
  { $project : { _id : false } }
])
```

An explanation is following.

First, we need to get rid of an array (`comments`). To do this we unwind the record; it gives us four records:

```
{
  "_id" : 21353456,
  "username" : "xy",
  "text" : "asdf",
  "comments" : {
    "username" : "User1",
    "text" : "hi"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : 21353456,
  "username" : "xy",
  "text" : "asdf",
  "comments" : {
    "username" : "User2",
    "text" : "hi1"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : 21353456,
  "username" : "xy",
  "text" : "asdf",
  "comments" : {
    "username" : "User3",
    "text" : "hi2"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : 21353456,
  "username" : "xy",
  "text" : "asdf",
  "comments" : {
    "username" : "User4",
    "text" : "hi3"
  }
}
```

Now we can group all the records into one applying a function to each field. First, we need to give criteria, the 'group by' field (or set of fields). In our case, it is simply the id: `_id: "$_id"`.

Then, for each field, we need to make a decision on how to include it into the resulting record. We have few fields: `username`, `text`, and `comments`. For each four records the username and text are the same, so we can easily pick any of them, namely `$first` or `$last`.

`comments`, however, are different. We want to preserve all of them so that we `$push` each one back.

The `hasComments` is a bit tricky here: we need to check if at least one `comment.username` contains the username. We can use `$eq: [...]` here, it will give us some array, e.g. `[true, false, false, false]` or `[false, false, true, false]`. We would need to pick which value goes into the resulting record. In this case, we can use neither `$first` nor `$last`. However, `$max` will give us an appropriate result.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and also has an accepted answer, but there is an easiest way than using `$unwind` and `$group`, only using `$project` like this:

The trick here is compare the intersection beetween `comments` array and desired value (in this case `User1`. If the interesection is greater than 0 (i.e. exists the value) then the field `existsUser` will be `true`, otherwise `false`.

```
{
  "$project": {
    "comments": 1,
    "existsUser": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
          "$gt": [
            {
              "$size": {
                "$setIntersection": [
                  "$comments.username",
                  [
                    "User1"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            },
            0
          ]
        },
        "then": true,
        "else": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YqfoAIlcB4x)