# Spring data mongodb query add boolean field if value exists in array

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to query some data from mongoDb which contains likes array. Each like object holds user.id of liker.

I need an extra `boolean` field that says if document is liked by user or not. So I need `isLiked` to be `true` if user has liked the document.

Here is what I have done till now:

I used ConditionalOperators.Cond to check if `likes.userId` is equal to `userId` of visitor.

```
    @Override
public List<PostExtra> findPostsNearBy(double[] point, Distance distance, String thisUserId) {
    mongoTemplate.indexOps(CheckInEntity.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("position"));

    ConditionalOperators.Cond conditionalOperators = new ConditionalOperators.ConditionalOperatorFactory(Criteria.where("likes.userId").is(thisUserId)).then(true).otherwise(false);


    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.geoNear(
                    locationBasedOperationHelper.findNear(point,distance)
                        .query(new Query(privacyConsideredOperationHelper.privacyConsideredQuery(userRelationsEntity)))
                    ,"distance"
            ),
            //Aggregation.unwind("likes"),
            Aggregation.project("user", "description").and(conditionalOperators).as("isLiked")
    );

    final AggregationResults<PostExtra> results =
            mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, PostEntity.class, PostExtra.class);
    return results.getMappedResults();
}
```

if I remove the comment on `Aggregation.unwind("likes")` I can only get posts that this user has liked not those he hasn't.

I have seen the same matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607221/mongodb-aggregation-project-check-if-array-contains) but I dont know whats the `MontoTemplate` code related to that?
Also I have seen approaches with `setIsSubset`, still I dont know java implementation.

I'm using spring boot `2.0.4.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`.

---

```
@Document(collection = EntityCollectionNames.POST_COLLECTION_NAME)
public class PostEntity{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    @DBRef
    @Indexed
    private UserEntity user;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    @Field(value = "position")
    private Point position;

    @Field(value = "description")
    private String description;

    @Field
    private int likesCount;
    @Field
    private List<LikeEntity> likes;
}
```

Post Extra:

```
public class PostExtra extends PostEntity {
    private double distance;
    private boolean isLiked;
}
```

Like:

```
public class LikeEntity {
    @Field
    private String userId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found out to do it without using `unwind` I need to implement something like this to project `isLiked` field:

```
$cond:[
    {$gt:[
        {$size:
            {$setIntersection:["$likes.userId",userIdsToCheckIn]}
        },0]
    },true,false]
```

I tried to do it in spring like this:

```
    ConditionalOperators.Cond conditionalOperators = new ConditionalOperators.ConditionalOperatorFactory(
            ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf(
                ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray(
                        SetOperators.SetIntersection.arrayAsSet("$likes.userId").intersects(????????)
                )
            ).greaterThanValue(0)
    ).then(true).otherwise(false);
```

But I didnt know what to pass to `intersects()` method and apparently Spring does not let you pass List or Array as that input. Then I found out I can implement my own `AggregationExpressions` and override `toDocument()` method.

So I came up with this and it worked:

```
ConditionalOperators.Cond conditionalOperators = new ConditionalOperators.ConditionalOperatorFactory(
                new AggregationExpression() {
                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                        return Document.parse("{$gt:[{$size:{$setIntersection:[\"$likes.userId\",[\""+userId+"\"]]}},0]}");
                    }
                }
        ).then(true).otherwise(false);
```

Ofcourse I could add $cond to the implementation directly too.

---

I would still like to know if there are any spring solutions that does not contain mongodb queries directly for this.